# why docker container gives different name when using bash to login

Tags: docker

`docker exec -it xxx /bin/bash` some containers give:
`root@ba5b2a06ef27:/usr/src/myapp#` some containers have `bash-4.2#`. I have compared the output of env, both hostname is a combination of number and letters. But just the login one is `root@xxxx`, the other one is `bash-4.2#`. why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just depends on the particular image & its configuration (specifically the `PS1` environment variable).

For example you can start a container using an Ubuntu image that has the environment variable set to the value `bash-4.2#`. Another container may be using exactly the same version of Ubuntu, but the `PS1` environment variable may be set to something different.